# Node import modules after executing code (or ESM Dynamic import)

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

i'm writing some code in nodejs and express, i need to execute some code BEFORE continuing to import modules.
My whole app has set up and uses modules with import instead of require and I can't change this setting.

In order to get some npm packages to work I have to run them BEFORE continuing with importing modules. Using commonJS and require () works perfectly, but with import I can't.

Even if I reverse the order of the modules or if I call them in different files they are all loaded FIRST and only afterwards my code is executed.

Example
start.js

```
import { mustBeLoadedAfterCode } from './second.js';
// some code here I need to execute first
```

second.js

```
import { mustBeLoadedAtTheEnd } from './third.js';
// some code here to execute at the end
```

In all my test, my code will be executed only AFTER have imported 'second.js' and all it relative imports.

Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

I've found a solution using dynamic imports:

```
let module = await import('./module.js');
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#Dynamic_Imports

https://v8.dev/features/dynamic-import